# Error MSVCP140.dll not found on python Geopandas installation

Tags: python, windows, dll, geopandas

I've installed Geopandas (a library that doesn't have a specific wheel for Windows). The pip install ran without problems but when I execute the script, it shows me an 'MSVCP140.dll not found' error.

The dll seems to be there and the permission on the temp for full control is ok too (as another post suggests in this web).

On the other hand, I read on a Python forum that this dll is causing problems because the numerous non compatible versions.

More info: this error is happening now, in a win 7 64 bits machine with py 3.5 32 bits, but in my last one it worked very well (win7 - 32 bits // python 3.4 - 32 bits).

I don't know what i'm missing.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: If the problem is shapely using ctypes to load geos_c.dll, then MSVCP140.dll needs to be installed to the System32 directory or a `PATH` directory. Installing [vc_redist.x86.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Non exactly shapely, but Geopandas.
Your answer sounds right though, so I'm going to try this, and next tell you how it goes.

Comment: @eryksun It worked!
I posted your comment like an answer so it can be voted ok.
I'm a kind of newbie in Stack Overflow. Sorry if this is not how it works (just tell me and I delete it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) said in his comment,

> then MSVCP140.dll needs to be installed to the System32 directory or
>   a PATH directory. Installing [vc_redist.x86.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) should resolve your
>   issue.

I post it here, because it solved my problem.

The fact that I change **from win 64 to 32** bits, but **I keep my python 32 bits** has caused the error.